# Set Proper Paths for Header, Footer and Plugin Files

Tags: php, html, path

Ok so here is my folder layout:

```
Car
  -bower_components
  -includes
  -logs
  -public
     --admin
     --css
     --fonts
     --img
     --js
  -vendor
```

In the root folder I have `paths.php`:

```
<?php

//$glock=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];


//if(!defined('ROOT')){define('ROOT',$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);}
if(!defined('ROOT')){define('ROOT',__DIR__.'/');}
if(!defined('INCLUDES')){define('INCLUDES',ROOT.'includes');}
if(!defined('LOGS')){define('LOGS',ROOT.'logs');}
if(!defined('ADMIN')){define('ADMIN',ROOT.'public/admin');}
if(!defined('CSS')){define('CSS',ROOT.'public/css');}
if(!defined('FONTS')){define('FONTS',ROOT.'public/fonts');}
if(!defined('IMG')){define('IMG',ROOT.'public/img');}
if(!defined('JS')){define('JS',ROOT.'public/js');}

?>
```

I'm using a template system so that I can call my CSS and HTML files from anywhere. I've been failing to call my `head-tag.php` file, which is in `includes`, into my `index.php` file. Here is my index file:

```
<?php

include('paths.php');

echo "<html lang='en'>";
echo "  <head>";

        include('includes/head-tag.php');   
echo"   </head>";

echo "  <body>";
echo "  <header>";
         include('includes/header.php');
echo "    </header>";
?>   
<main>...
```

And here is `head-tag.php`:

```
        ...

        <!--Include all stylesheetes-->
        <link href=<?php echo CSS."/main.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=<?php echo CSS."/bootstrap.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=<?php echo CSS."/carousel.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=<?php echo CSS."/cars.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=<?php echo CSS."/footer.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=<?php echo CSS."/loader.css"; ?> rel="stylesheet">

        <!--DateTimePicker JS includes-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

I've tried echoing the paths in my `head-tag.php` file, but it only gives me the file directory, and not the one on the server, which generates a "Not allowed to load local resource" error. I know I'm doing something wrong here but I can't pin it down. I've been trying for over 24 hours now. In my `paths.php` file, I've tried using `str_replace()` to get rid of the "C:/..." and replace it with "localhost:8080..." but it didn't work, unless I was doing it wrong, I don't know. Any suggestions? Something tells me I'll have to define the paths again in my `head-tag.php file`, which I'm kinda trying to avoid.

**TL;DR**
How do I get `head-tag.php` to echo "localhost:8080..." instead of file:///C:/wamp64/www/..."

**UPDATE:**
I sorta solved this initial problem but now I have a new one. I answered my own question below and presented the new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I sorta kinda found the solution. In my paths file, instead of having `if(!defined('ROOT')){define('ROOT',__DIR__.'/');}`, I now have `if(!defined('ROOT')){define('ROOT',dirname(dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']))));}`
. Now when I try to access the header files from another php file which is not in the root, it doesn't work. I've found that the reason that happens is that it still determines the root from the file, which I thought I ran away from when I stopped using `__DIR__`and`__FILE__`. So how do I set the root folder to be constant, no matter which file/folder I'm calling from?